# Sync object not getting keyset

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, key

I have a custom object of Sync Tracking that allows to keep track for Users , when they are doing a sync from their ipad to salesforce. Now I need to write a trigger on that object, Sync Tracking which is a Veeva object. Is that possible? I tried below trigger.

Trigger:

```
trigger CallSync on Sync_Tracking_vod__c (after insert, after update) {
Set<ID> ids = Trigger.new.keySet();
List<Sync_Tracking_vod__c> SyncTrack= 
            [SELECT  id,Successful_Sync_vod__c
                      FROM Sync_Tracking_vod__c
                     where id =:ids];
}
```

Error:

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [LIST].keySet()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your code to:

```
trigger CallSync on Sync_Tracking_vod__c (after insert, after update) { 
    Set <Id> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet(); 
    List<Sync_Tracking_vod__c> SyncTrack = [SELECT id,Successful_Sync_vod__c 
                                            FROM Sync_Tracking_vod__c where id IN:ids]; 
}
```